# looking for the best way to see when my task is complete C#

Tags: c#, task

So I'm pulling in a list of items and for each item I'm creating an instance of an object to run a task on that item. All the objects are the same, they updated based off of a received message every three seconds. This update does not all occur at once though, sometimes it takes 3.1 seconds, etc. This is data I need to serialize in XML once it all exists so I'm looking for a way to see when its all done.

I've explored tasks in .net 4.6 but that initiates a task and it reports complete and then to run again the task class would initiate it again but in my case that won't work because each instance stays alive and initiates itself when a new message comes in.

What is the best way to have it report it reached the last line of code and then look at a list of these instances and say when all of them show as complete then run task to serialize?

I've included code below of the instance that is running.

```
private void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            var eventArgs = new CallDataReceivedEventArgs();
            this.OnCallDataReceived(eventArgs);

            try
            {
                List<Tuple<String, TimeSpan>> availInItems = new List<Tuple<string, TimeSpan>>();
                List<Tuple<string, int, TimeSpan, string, string, string>> agentlist = new List<Tuple<string, int, TimeSpan, string, string, string>>();

                if (e == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                List<TimeSpan> listOfTimeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();
                if (e.CmsData != null)
                {
                    #region Gathering Agent Information
                    // Create a list of all timespans for all _agents in a queue using the property AgentTimeInState

                    foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
                    {
                        //AgentData = new ScoreBoardAgentDataModel(AgentName, AgentExtension, AgentTimeInState, AgentAuxReason, AgentId, AgentAdcState);

                        _agentData.AgentName = item.AgName;

                        _agentData.AgentExtension = item.Extension;

                        _agentData.AgentAuxReason = item.AuxReasonDescription;

                        _agentData.AgentId = item.LoginId;

                        _agentData.AgentAcdState = item.WorkModeDirectionDescription;

                        _agentData.AgentTimeInState = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;

                        _agentData.TimeSubmitted = DateTime.Now;

                        agentlist.Add(Tuple.Create(_agentData.AgentName, _agentData.AgentExtension, _agentData.AgentTimeInState, _agentData.AgentId, _agentData.AgentAcdState, _agentData.AgentAuxReason));

                        if (_agentData.AgentAcdState == "AVAIL")
                        {
                            listOfTimeSpans.Add(_agentData.AgentTimeInState);

                            availInItems.Add(Tuple.Create(_agentData.AgentName, _agentData.AgentTimeInState));
                        }

                        availInItems.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.Item2.CompareTo(t2.Item2));
                    }

                    var availInAgents =
                        agentlist
                            .Where(ag => ag.Item5 == "AVAIL")
                            .ToList();

                    availInAgents.Sort((t1, t2) =>
                        t1.Item3.CompareTo(t2.Item3));

                    var max3 = availInAgents.Skip(availInAgents.Count - 3);

                    max3.Reverse();

                    _agents.AgentsOnBreak = 0;
                    foreach (var agent in agentlist)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(agent.Item6) && agent.Item6.StartsWith("Break"))
                        {
                            _agents.AgentsOnBreak++;
                        }
                    }

                    _agents.AgentsOnLunch = 0;
                    foreach (var agent in agentlist)
                    {
                        //If the current agent's aux reason is Lunch
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(agent.Item6) && agent.Item6.StartsWith("Lunch"))
                        {
                            //add one to agentsonlunch
                            _agents.AgentsOnLunch++;
                        }
                    }

                    _agents.NextInLine = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var agent in max3.Reverse())
                    {
                        //assign agent to NextInLine and start a new line
                        _agents.NextInLine += agent.Item1 + Environment.NewLine;
                        //reverse NextInLine
                        _agents.NextInLine.Reverse();
                    }

                    _agents.TimeSubmitted = DateTime.Now;

                    #endregion

                    #region Gathering Skill Information

                    _skillData.OldestCall = e.CmsData.Skill.OldestCall;
                    _skillData.AgentsStaffed = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsStaffed;
                    _skillData.AgentsAuxed = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsInAux;
                    _skillData.AgentsAvailable = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable;
                    _skillData.AgentsOnCalls = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsOnAcdCall;
                    _skillData.CallsWaitingInQueue = e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing;
                    _skillData.Asa = e.CmsData.Skill.AnswerTimePerAcdCall;
                    _skillData.TimeSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
                    _skillData.EstimatedHoldTimeLow = e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeLow;
                    _skillData.EstimatedHoldTimeMedium = e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeMedium;
                    _skillData.EstimatedHoldTimeHigh = e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeHigh;     
                    #endregion

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Info(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also please make an complete and as possible short example, that will represent your problem. I really don't want to dig in to this code.

Comment: Maybe use [System.Threading.Tasks Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks(v=vs.110).aspx) kind of depends of what you want to achieve..

Comment: or add a Finaly to that TryCatch block and in the finally print "Done", play a sound, connect a external device that launches a rocket.. I really don't know what you mean with "...best way to see when my task is complete..." :p then you can see

Comment: call me blind - I dont see any tasks in your code

Comment: @BugFinder you found a bug :p

Answer (score 3):

With tasks you can start many at the same time and wait for them all to finish like this:

```
var taskList = new List<Task>();

foreach (var thingToDo in work)
{
   taskList.Add(thingToDo.StartTask());
}

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

This way you can run everything in parallel and wont get after the last line until everything is done.

**Edit following your comment**

You can embed your work in a task with this:

```
public async Task DoWork() 
{
    var taskList = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var thingToDo in work)
    {
       taskList.Add(thingToDo.StartTask());
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: ok this is what i want, but this is where it gets more difficult because i need the process at the end to tell the task it is complete and when it triggers again to mark it not complete until its done again and marked as complete. basically the same task runs over and over again but the task is calling the Hey i'm not complete and hey i'm complete statement.

Comment: can you point me towards some documentation on how to setup my job to work with this task?